# Byobu / Tmux copy whole line

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen, byobu

I use byobu in tmux mode. In screen I can do this:

```
Ctrl+a [, move to line, Y, Ctrl+a ]
```

"Y" copys the whole line into the clipboard. I am looking to something similar in byobu in tmux mode. The only thing I found is:

```
Ctrl+a/b (depends on your setting) + [, move to line, 0, space, $, enter, Ctrl+a/b + ]
```

But I feel like that is a lot of hard to reach keystrokes, Y is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an improvement: do `space, V, enter` instead of `0, space, $, enter`. A single <kbd>V</kbd> is a lot easier to type than a <kbd>0</kbd> and a <kbd>$</kbd>. <kbd>V</kbd> is equivalent to vim's "do visual mode select of entire line" command.

I can't speak to byobu directly but since it's just fronting tmux, you could also bind a key to all this in native tmux. Something like this:

```
bind-key -r -T copy-mode-vi Y send-keys -X begin-selection \; send-keys -X select-line \; send-keys -X copy-selection
```

Then you just enter copy mode, go to the line you want to copy, press <kbd>Y</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The line will now be in the paste buffer. (While that's a bit long and ugly it does work for me.)

**Edit:** Tested with tmux 2.4

Answer (score 0):

I have in my ~/.byobu/.tmux.conf

```
bind-key -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection                                                                                                                                 
bind-key -t vi-copy 'y' copy-selection
```

so normally I can enter in copy mode by:

Prefix + [

then I can use vi commands to navigate and enter vi select mode by 'v'
yank the selection by 'y'

after that I can put/paste in the terminal by:

Prefix + ]

In order to copy a line:

```
    Prefix + [
    navigate to the line
    $ (jump to the end)
    Left Arrow
    v (begin-selection)
    0 (jump to the start of the line)
    y (yank and exit copy mode)

    Prefix + ] (paste the line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer for the original question.

You need the following line in the config:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi Y send-keys -X end-of-line \; send-keys -X cursor-left \; send-keys -X begin-selection \; send-keys -X start-of-line \; send-keys -X copy-selection-and-cancel
```

Answer (score -1):

Because of newer Tmux version I had to change my config:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send-keys -X begin-selection                                                                                                                 
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-selection \; send-keys -X cancel
```

Thanks to 'rushiagr' (http://www.rushiagr.com/blog/2016/06/16/everything-you-need-to-know-about-tmux-copy-pasting-ubuntu)